# Wordpress Woocommerce Rest API, No Response code in POST method

Tags: php, wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create an e-commerce application using Flutter and Woocommerce, so I am using **Woocommerce Rest API** for the same, but I am not able to perform the POST method successfully, I mean, there is no response code being received, and the after a few minutes I receive Response Code 502, the GET method is working fine, also the data is being updated at the dashboard, but still not receiving any response code and unless I am unable to get the response code, the app will be useless.

I tried the POST method using Postman and tried to send data as per the documentation, but still no good.

Cannot find any possible solution for the same, please help.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are suffering from this error, the problem is with your server, try to host your Wordpress Site on different Cloud Platform, mine was on AWS, which I moved to a different one, and this worked.